# Why grouping in a subquery causes problems

Tags: sql, sap-ase

When I include the 2 commented out lines in the following subquery, seems that it takes forever until my Sybase 12.5 ASE server gets any results. Without these 2 lines the query runs ok. What is so wrong with that grouping?

```
select days_played.day_played, count(distinct days_played.user_id) as OLD_users
from days_played inner join days_received
on days_played.day_played = days_received.day_received
and days_played.user_id = days_received.user_id
where days_received.min_bulk_MT > days_played.min_MO
and days_played.user_id in

(select sgia.user_id 
from days_played as sgia
where sgia.day_played < days_played.day_played
--group by sgia.user_id 
--having sum(sgia.B_first_msg) = 0
)

group by days_played.day_played
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found out what the problem was
I had to include user id in the subquery: "where days_played.user_id = sgia.user_id
and sgia.day_played < days_played.day_played"

Comment: The point is that using `exists` is better than using `in` in this case, because you have to use an index then.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what the query does by using showplan to show the explanation.

In this case Can't you eliminate the subquery by making it part of the main query?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try rewriting the query as follows?

```
select days_played.day_played,
       count(distinct days_played.user_id) as OLD_users
  from days_played
 inner join days_received on days_played.day_played = days_received.day_received
                         and days_played.user_id = days_received.user_id
 where days_received.min_bulk_MT > days_played.min_MO
   and 0 = (select sum(sgia.B_first_msg)
              from days_played as sgia
             where sgia.user_id = days_played.user_id
               and sgia.day_played < days_played.day_played
            )
 group by days_played.day_played
```

I guess this should give you better performance...